# ruby-aaws Get specific Album

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get a specific music cd from Amazon using ruby-aaws.

```
il = ItemSearch.new( 'Music', { 'Artist' => artist_title,
                                'Title' => album_name } )
rg = ResponseGroup.new( 'Large' )

req = Request.new(AMAZON_KEY_ID, AMAZON_ASSOCIATES_ID, 'de')
resp = req.search( il, rg, 5)
```

But this fails. It only seems to work when I search for artist *or* title, not both at the same time. What am I making wrong? If I construct the url by hand, it works prefectly, but I really don't want to parse the xml manually myself.

Comment: Did you try setting $DEBUG? Did you get anywhere?

Comment: Sadly no. I am now parsing the xml by hand.

Comment: Do you get an error message or do you just not get any results?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bit of a look at the code of `ruby-aaws`. It looks like you should be able to set `$DEBUG` to `true` before calling any of the `ruby-aaws` methods/classes and see what URLs are being requested. If there are any discrepancies between your handcrafted URL and the one being generated by `ruby-aaws`, this might give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this use-case with the latest version of ruby-aaws and it works just fine.

I used the following for the ItemSearch (with the same code you posted initially):

```
il = ItemSearch.new( 'Music', { 'Artist'=>'The Smiths', 'Title'=>'Hatful' })
```

and got good results back as I would expect.  Please try again and see if perhaps the latest ruby-aaws has ironed out a wrinkle which was stopping you.